# doClick() method of JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

doClick() method of JButton triggers actionPerformed Method, but I want to trigger paintComponent() by use of doClick() method! Please help!

This is what is suggested? Here i have a label whose text is being changed every time a doClick() method's action is performed. But unfortunately, paintComponent method does not execute the same number of times as the actionPerformed() method. This is just the code what is suggested as Answer. I actually want to trigger doClick() method when data is being read from the file and diffrent shapes are painted according to data in the text file!

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
public class myFrame {
JFrame jFrame;
myPanel bpanel;
JButton jbutton;
int radius;
JLabel label; 
public myFrame() {
    jFrame=new JFrame();
    bpanel=new myPanel();
    jbutton=new JButton("presss");
     radius=50; 
     label=new JLabel(radius+" "); 
     bpanel.add(jbutton); 
     bpanel.add(label);  
     jbutton.addActionListener(new myButtonListener());
     for (int i=0; i< 5; i++)
         jbutton.doClick(); 
     jFrame.getContentPane().add(bpanel);
     jFrame.pack(); 
     jFrame.setVisible(true); 
 }
 public class myPanel extends JPanel {
      public myPanel() {
          setBackground(Color.cyan); 
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400)); 
      }
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paint component triggered"); 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(0,0,radius,radius); 
      }
 }
 private class myButtonListener implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          radius=radius+20; 
          label.setText(radius+" ");
          bpanel.repaint(); 
          System.out.println("mouse click event triggered"); 
     }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new myFrame();
            }
        }); 
 }
```

}

Comment: Why would you need this? In any case, just add an `ActionListener` to the button: `button.addActionListener(e -> repaint());`

Comment: As written, your code calls GUI operations from the main thread rather than the event dispatch thread, which is invalid. You're also calling all of your updates before the component is even painted the first time.

Comment: What's the *real* problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to get data from file and then trigger events according to the read data!

Comment: Then show your *real* code, with examples of how you expect the file to work. As it is, you've just thrown some sloppy code into the question with no explanation. Do you really expect anything good to come from that?

Answer (score 2):

> but I want to trigger paintComponent() by use of doClick() method!

Swing components should be smart enough to repaint themselves when a property of the component is changed.

For example if you use the `setText(...)` method on a JLabel the label repaints itself with the specified text.

So when you click on a button you should just be changing a property of your class by invoking a method of the class. Then in that method you invoke `repaint()` and the component will repaint itself.

Edit:

> n modify so that paintComponent method also executes for the same number of times as actionPerformed() is executing

There are several problems with the code:

1. The frame isn't visible invoking the doClick() method will have no effect since the component will only be painted once the frame is visible. So the animation code needs to be executed AFTER the frame is visible
2. You can't use a loop. One of two things will happen: a) The loop will execute so fast you won't see the incremental painting of the component or b) the repaint() request will be made to the RepaintManager who will combine each request into a single paint request.

If you want to do animation then you need to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation.

Comment: please see the explanation of code suggested.... n modify so that paintComponent method also executes for the same number of times as actionPerformed() is executing.

Comment: Thanks for the help...yes, applying loop was the problem due to which repaint() was executing only once...adopted a different approach to solve the issue! made a few objects in the loop n solved it !

Comment: @NAVEEDNAWAZ, glad the suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark, so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @camickr I find Swing components often do not change after properties change and manually repainting, revalidating, and all sorts of stuff are necessary to ensure proper onscreen rendering of components. This is a continual frustration I have with Swing. I do not have these problems with React. Therefore, knowing how to trigger a repaint seems like a valid concern.